# How to display an input only if certain conditions are met in Python

Tags: python, input

I'm trying to make my code display an extra input if a certain condition is met (in this case, selecting "Y")

This is what I've tried:

```
    if RandomNum != UserGuess:
        print("Sorry, you guessed wrong. The number was: ", RandomNum)
        KeepGuess = input("Would you like to continue guessing? (Y/N): ").upper()
    elif KeepGuess == "Y":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

When I do this, I get the  following error:

```
  elif KeepGuess == "Y":
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'KeepGuess' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Set the value `KeepGuess` above`if RandomNum`

Comment: You'll want to think on `KeepGuess == "Y"` as a condition of it's own, not as _alternative_ to `RandomNum != UserGuess`. The way it's written now, means _if the number was guessed_  (so, first condition was not fulfilled), see if `KeepGuess == "Y"`. But if first condition was not met, then `KeepGuess = ....` was never exectuted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the error says, you are trying to use a variable that does not exist yet, you can move the elif-else part in the same block that KeepGuess is defined:

```
if RandomNum != UserGuess:
    print("Sorry, you guessed wrong. The number was: ", RandomNum)
    KeepGuess = input("Would you like to continue guessing? (Y/N): ").upper()
    if KeepGuess == "Y":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code only creates and assigns the KeepGuess variable when the if statement returns true. You want to move the first elif statement into the first if statement and change it to an if. So it will look like the code below. You will also want to change continue to call what ever function is making the loop. I hope this helps

```
   def Check():
       UserGuess = input('Guess Here:')
        if RandomNum != UserGuess:
            print("Sorry, you guessed wrong. The number was: ", RandomNum)
            KeepGuess = input("Would you like to continue guessing? (Y/N): 
            ").upper()
            if KeepGuess == "Y":
                Check()
        else:
            print(rest of your code here)
```